# How can you use a floating point number as an exponent in c

Tags: c, function, math, floating-point, exponent

I am running this simple piece of c code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"

int main()
{
float i = 5.5;
float score = 0;

score=i/(i+(2^i));

}
```

and the editor says that the float i "must be an integral or unscoped enum value", and it is essential that i remains a float. How do I use a float as an exponent in c ?

Comment: `^` is not exponentiation in C! Read a tutorial on C before making any unfounf assumptions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
score=i/(i+(2^i));
```

to this:

```
score = i / (i + pow(2, i));
```

---

`^` is the XOR operator, you need [pow(double base, double exponent)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/); putting everything together:

```
#include "math.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        float i = 5.5;
        float score = 0;

        score = i / (i + pow(2, i));
        printf("%f\n", score);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ gcc -Wall main.c -lm -o main
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ ./main 
0.108364
```

---

As of [c99](/questions/tagged/c99), as njuffa mentioned, you can use [exp2(float n)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp2):

> Computes 2 raised to the given power n.

and instead of:

```
pow(2, i)
```

use:

```
exp2f(i)
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: Great @J.doo, don't forget to *accept* an answer!

Comment: Probably better to use `exp2f(i)` here instead of `pow(2,i)` in terms of performance and accuracy, and arguably clearer.

Comment: @njuffa I didn't know that function. However, I had to admit that I had to actually read the ref (!) to understand what `i` does (but already knew pretty much because of your comment)! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In C the expression

```
2^i
```

uses the bitwise XOR operator `^`, this is not an exponent, hence the advice that `i` must be integer type.

Try using the math function `pow` such as with

```
score = i / (i + pow(2,i));
```